# Classification tree greedy algorithm

Tags: cart

I have learnt about the greedy algorithm in building a tree. However, I believe that it is "greedy" because at each iteration of the split, we only decrease the impurity locally, rather than globally. So I was wondering if anyone could give me a simple example of one where I use the algorith, and the first split is actually worse than the second split in terms of decreasing impurity.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you were looking for: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222125/78313

Comment: I'm still looking for a reference of the non-greedy algorithm.